# Encontrar div id com variações - Web Scraping - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supondo que eu tenha as seguintes div ids

```
<div id='post_message_12932087>
    <p>random text</p>
</div>

<div id='post_message_21390123>
    <p>random text2</p>
</div>

<div id='post_message_23190495>
    <p>random text3</p>
</div>
```

Como eu faria para pegar os dados (usando o find_all()) de cada uma dessas div ids, sendo o padrão de cada div id o seguinte "post_message_numero"?

```
pagina.find_all('div', {'id', 'post_message_xxxx'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o selector equivalente de CSS para atributos que checa se o ID começa com como `post_message_`: `[atributo^=valor]`

O seletor deve ser algo como `div[id^=post_message_]` junto com o método `select()` do *Beautiful Soup* ou `select_one()` se desejar pegar só a primeira ocorrência, exemplo:

```
pagina.select('div[id^=post_message_]')
```

Para pegar apenas o primeiro:

```
pagina.select_one('div[id^=post_message_]')
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muitíssimo obrigado!